# Visual Studio 2005 product codes?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005

Where can i find visual studio product codes for -

```
Microsoft Visual Basic
Microsoft C#
Microsoft Crystal Reports
```

Etc.. that have been installed?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere deep in the registry :).
You'll have to dig up the license keys if you've already installed these products.  No one in there right mind is going to post their key.